# How to find all users that work in same company as mine?

Tags: support, profile-page, data-explorer

I would like to find all users that have a login to Stack Overflow and that work in my company.

To do that, I have seen that I can create a custom query on
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/875590#resultSets

In UserProfile, there exists a field named `at` in `Current Position` that (if used) must normally specify in which company a user is working.

In which database table is this field defined so that I can use this field to query StackExchange user datatable ?

If this field is not accessible, can it be added ? Is there another solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. It's a Stack Overflow specific field, taken from a column/table that is not filled and likely not even *present* in the databases of other Stack Exchange sites. SEDE only supports the 'greatest common divisor' of the sites, and the same holds for the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: So the only solution would be to ask to all guy in my company to flag AboutMe field with a specific tag like `<company>MyCompany</company>` !?

Comment: Yes. But right now, they aren't required to fill in their position and company either. You might have more colleagues here than you know ...

Comment: Yes, it is correct but I regret only that "Company" field is not a generic field to all StackExchange sites :-)